# ID4175: The issuer of the security token was not recognized by the IssuerNameRegistry

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, certificate, wif

I am trying to implement a Simple STS web site alongside my MVC application in a development environment. I was able to get this working properly on my local machine. I would navigate to my MVC app, kicked out to the STS web application, I login, then am redirected back to my MVC app. This is not using AFDS by the way.

When I migrated this to my Development environment, I see similar activity but I get the error below when I login. I have checked about 20 times that my thumbprint in the MVC app is the exact same as the cert.

(The login is working fine as I don't get redirected until the authentication succeeds.)

Any guesses?

Error message I recieve:

> ID4175: The issuer of the security token was not recognized by the IssuerNameRegistry. To accept security tokens from this issuer, configure the IssuerNameRegistry to return a valid name for this issuer

web.config from STS website:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="IssuerName" value="STSTestCert"/>
<add key="SigningCertificateName" value="CN=STSTestCert"/>
<add key="EncryptingCertificateName" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
```

web.config from MVC application:

```
<microsoft.identityModel>
<service>
  <audienceUris>
    <add value="http://localhost/" />
  </audienceUris>
  <federatedAuthentication>
    <wsFederation passiveRedirectEnabled="true" issuer="http://localhost:57543/mySTS/" realm="http://localhost/" requireHttps="false" />
    <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
  </federatedAuthentication>
  <applicationService>
    <claimTypeRequired>
      <!--Following are the claims offered by STS 'http://localhost:57543/mySTS/'. Add or uncomment claims that you require by your application and then update the federation metadata of this application.-->
      <claimType type="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" optional="true" />
      <claimType type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" optional="true" />
    </claimTypeRequired>
  </applicationService>
  <issuerNameRegistry type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35">
        <trustedIssuers>
      <add thumbprint="‎11111" name="http://localhost:57543/mySTS/" />
        </trustedIssuers>
      </issuerNameRegistry>
    </service>
  </microsoft.identityModel>
```

Comment: You ever get this worked out? Am getting the same error myself right now.

Comment: Same question as Matt.  Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Copying your thumbprint adds hidden unicode characters.  Try typing it in.

Comment: This so very much, I wish I had found this out sooner thanks!

Answer (score 5):

As MJCoffman mentioned it is most probably because you copied the thumbprint with hidden character. [You can find more details here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2023835/en-us)

Comment: From the given link: "When using certificates snap-in and certificate GUI, do NOT copy "extra space" that appears before the certificate thumbpint from the Richedit control."

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was also that copying the thumbprint and pasting it was adding some characters that a regular text editor do not show.  I found the following instructions very useful to remove the special characters (look #4). [posted by Edwin Guru Singh](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1974460-c916-462c-97d6-4ec3e33005d9/how-to-solve-id4175-the-issuer-of-the-security-token-was-not-recognized-by-the?forum=wcf)

Do this to get rid of the special characters using Visual Studio:

1. Close the web.config
2. Right-click on it and open it with binary editor
3. Find where the thumbprint is and delete additional characters (everything that is not a number, usually dots).
4. Save and try again, it should work.